# How do I read from a StreamReader with a while loop in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

Consider:

```
Dim line As String
Using readFile As New StreamReader(SalesUpdateFile)

While (line = readFile.ReadLine) IsNot Nothing
```

I am  new to Visual Basic. And every time I run this code it gives me this error:

> "IS" requires an operand that have a reference type

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an assignment as an expression in VB. Instead you should do something similar to this:

```
line = readFile.ReadLine
While (line IsNot Nothing)
    'process the line
     line = readFile.ReadLine
End While
```

Comment: This coding isn't nice. Heinzi's code is much better to read.

Answer (score 5):

While Konamiman's answer is perfectly fine, I don't like to [repeat myself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and, thus, prefer the following pattern to avoid duplicating the call to `ReadLine()`:

```
Do
    Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
    If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    ' Process the line
Loop
```

Comment: This solution also works better when there are Continue statements within the do loop which would skip the final `ReadLine` call or require additional duplication of `ReadLine` calls.

Answer (score 2):

The while loop you have in your code is an idiom specific to C#. Take a look at this example on MSDN for the VB.NET equivalent:

*[StreamReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Do
     Dim line = reader.ReadLine()           
     ' Process the line
Loop until line is Nothing
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Comment: if line is nothing processing it will fail,see Heinzi solution