# Single line Readline()! = null in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I read from a StreamReader with a while loop in Visual Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714234/while-in-vb-to-make-a-read-from-stream-reader)

In C# I would loop a streamreader as shown below.

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    list.Add(line); // Add to list.
    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
}
```

What's the Equivalent in VB.NET?

I tried

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) IsNot Nothing)
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C#, `((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)` is an **assignment inside an expression**. VB does not support that. Thus, you will have to split

- the assignment `line = reader.ReadLine()` and
- the comparison `line != null` (in VB: `line IsNot Nothing`)

There are many ways to do that. One has been presented by Prasanna [in a parallel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418703/87698). This is the one I'd prefer, since you do not need to repeat the `ReadLine` call:

```
Do
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
    If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
    line = reader.ReadLine()
    Do Until line Is Nothing
     Console.WriteLine(line)
     line = reader.ReadLine()
    Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

In VB you can only do an assignment in a statement, there is actually a command for that:

```
Let line = reader.ReadLine()
```

The `Let` command can be implicit, so you don't need to write it. Actually the editor will automatically change it to the implicit form:

```
line = reader.ReadLine()
```

Although the `Let` command isn't visible, it's still there lurking. You can't use an assignment as an expression like you can in C#. If you try, you will be using the comparison operator `=` instead of the assignment operator `=`. They are the same, and they can be as one is only used in an assignment, and the other is only used in an expression.

You can check for null after the assignment and exit the loop:

```
Do
  line = reader.ReadLine()
  If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
  Console.WriteLine(line)
Loop
```